# Indexing a batch of lists of vectors with a batch of indices, where there are an arbitrary number of batch dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

This question generalises a previously asked question: [Indexing a list of list of vectors with a list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75604871/19247883)

Given some data represented as a array of dimensions (N1,..., Nk, L, H), and a batch of indices of dimensions (N1,..., Nk), how can I index the data such that the output is of dimensions (N1,..., Nk, H). Semantically, I'd like to replace the below for loops with a single NumPy call:

```py
N1, N2 = (3, 3, 3), ()
L, H = 5, 2

data = np.arange(np.prod(N1) * L * H).reshape(*N1, L, H)
inds = np.arange(np.prod(N1), dtype=int).reshape(N1) % L
out = np.empty((*N1, H), dtype=data.dtype)
for ii in np.ndindex(N1):
    out[ii] = data[ii + (inds[ii],)]
assert out.shape == (3, 3, 3, 2)

data = np.arange(np.prod(N2) * L * H).reshape(*N2, L, H)
inds = np.arange(np.prod(N2), dtype=int).reshape(N2) % L
out = np.empty((*N2, H), dtype=data.dtype)
for ii in np.ndindex(N2):
    out[ii] = data[ii + (inds[ii],)]
assert out.shape == (2,)
```

Seems like flattening the batch dimensions could work, but is there utilities in NumPy capable of indexing as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the answer in the linked post by repeating `np.arange(N_i)` as the index for each batch dimension i, in a way that the final result broadcasts to form a (N1, ..., Nk) shaped array. Numpy provides various index tricks to help with this. While there are multiple options, I think [`np.ogrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) might work best:

```
import numpy as np

N1, N2, N3, L, H = 5, 3, 4, 10, 6

data = np.random.rand(N1, N2, N3, L, H)
inds = np.random.randint(L, size=(N1, N2, N3))

# We need an index tuple with 4 arrays that broadcast to (N1, N2, N3):
idx = tuple(np.ogrid[:N1, :N2, :N3]) + (inds,)

out = data[idx]
```

`out.shape`:

```
(5, 3, 4, 6) # Which is (N1, N2, N3, H), as required
```

---

There is also [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html), though I find it a bit more awkward/less direct, because you need to explicitly align and then remove dimensions:

```
out = np.take_along_axis(data, inds[..., None, None], axis=3).squeeze()
```